# Is there any way to disable some of the hardware buttons?

Tags: buttons

This happens to me all the time:
I read my RSS news, view some article and turn my device to landscape mode. When I am manipulating (turning) the device I accidentally press some of the buttons. This became to be very annoying as I am always pressing the search button or the camera button.

Also when I pass my phone to anybody, the very first thing EVERYONE does is pressing the search button accidentally and passing me phone back with words "I didn't do anything!".

Can I disable hardware buttons somehow?

Comment: No, the hardware buttons cannot be disabled.

Comment: No, in Windows Phone the hardware buttons cannot be disabled

Comment: Good question, not useful answer. Only thing that helps here: get hardware that actually has hardware buttons (the clickety-click sounding ones) and not those crappy capacitive buttons integrated into screen area. But there isn't much real choice here, I'm afraid.. :-/

Comment: I wonder if a rooted phone could do this.

Comment: According to @ChristiaanV comment on his answer, this is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't!

I have seen this question also coming by in the development area where people would like to disable these buttons because of the same behaviour you describe here.

I think that this is the backside of the buttons being integrated into the screen instead of 'real' hardware buttons which you can see and feel when you are pressing them.

Maybe this would be something to mention on the [Uservoice](http://windowsphone7community.uservoice.com/forums/107603-bug-feedback) site of microsoft. I can imagine that there a factors that could determine if you would press the button or that you did it unintentionally. Maybe by determining the angle of the device or that if an application is running that you need to hold the buttons a bit longer before it activates the command behind it.

For now there is unfortunately no solution for this behaviour.

Comment: For the camera button, one idea would be to develop a dummy camera application that would simply exit.

Answer (score 2):

No. Hardware buttons will be always left enabled for quick search or jumping to the home screen to access other apps. The back button can be long pressed (to see the background apps) or single pressed to go back to the app you jumped out off.